# Convergence in Probability not implying Convergence in Distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, expected-value, weak-convergence

I would immensely appreciate a little help here.

I am suffering with the following statement: "Convergence in probability implies Convergence in distribution"

Let U $\sim$ Uniform($0$,$1$). Let $X_n$ = \begin{cases} 
      n  &  U\leq \frac{1}{n} \\
      0 &otherwise&  
   \end{cases}

Clearly $X_n \to 0  $

However: E($X_n$) = $(\frac{1}{n} \times n  ) + (\frac{n-1}{n} \times 0 ) = 1$ $ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}
$

So E($X_n$) $  \not \to  $ E($0$) = $0$ Despite $X_n \to 0  $

Any help would really help me out lots.
Oskar :)

Comment: Convergence in distribution does not imply convergence of the expectation. It does imply convergence of the expectation of a *bounded* function of the random variable. But in general the identity is not bounded.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the meaning of convergence in distribution. The example you give does not violate this statement. It only says that convergence in probability does not guarantee convergence in $L^1$.

Comment: Such enormous thank you to both of you ! This has been on my mind all day ! I see now that convergance of Cos(Xn) would convergace but the identity is an unbounded map!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

To show that the given sequence converges in Law it is enough to calculate

$$F_{X_n}(t)=\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if $t<0$} \\
1-\frac{1}{n},  & \text{if $0\leq t<n$} \\
1, & \text{if $t\geq n$}
\end{cases}$$

and its limit

$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} F_{X_n}(t)=\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if $t<0$} \\
1, & \text{if $t\geq 0$}
\end{cases}$$

Thus $X_n \xrightarrow{d}0$